# RegExp as table entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, twilio

I'm building an application that takes inputs from SMS text thru Twilio.  I'd like to build a table the matches the incoming SMS body with the appropriate response.

For example, imagine I'm building an NFL text message thing.

Someone texts in 'Redskins' and we text back, "The Redskins play at FedEx field"
Someone texts in 'Colts' and we text back, "The Colts are the pride of Indiana."

Here's the tricky part:

Of course, our Rails app is going to need to interpret the incoming team names through Regular Expressions, as many people will text in:  Redskins or REDSKINS or REDSKIN or Redskin or REDskin.....

With one or two teams, one could just hardcode the RegExp and response into the controller...but with 30 teams, that seems wrong.  (And with 120 entries -- say all pro sports-- even worse).

Does any one have any tips on getting the team names from the input stage, thru the DB table stage with a 'RegExp' conversion in the middle?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for a modest number of keywords, I recommend a two table approach with Keywords and Aliases, always stores in lower case. Convert input to lower case. For each Keyword (say, redskins) you manually add 5-10 variations (including the correct one) in Aliases all of which have Alias.keyword_id = the id of the keyword. So you simply search Alias for the user input, and if you find a match you have the keyword_id of the keyword.

It has two advantages: fast and easy to extend... i fyou log the "no matches" you'll get a list of new aliases to add once to the dbase. MUCH easier and more reliable than trying to do via regex.

Comment: you're welcome. i've gotten a lot of help here on stackoverflow and am happy when i get a chance to return the favor!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you want regexps here. What about spelling errors? For helpfulness (esp coming from a txt msg) I think you want to allow shortenings too.

Maybe a [Soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex)-based library or spelling correction thing would be best. You want a nearest match algorithm not a patterned match one.

Answer (score 0):

If the text message is not too long, you should first chop that into words, and then take an intersection with the list of team names.

```
array_of_team_names = %w(Redskins Colts ... ) # keep it all capitalized
'cOLts blah blah'.scan(/\w+/).map{|word| word.capitalize} & array_of_team_names
# => ['Colts']
```

If you want to handle mistypes as suggested by drysdam, or if you want to handle larger text with more accuracy, you should use some library specific to that.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking is "how do I avoid hardcoding a regexp into my code, since I might have a lot of them, and they are really a data element"?

If you want to do the matching with regexp, you should note that you can create a regexp from a string, so you could easily have a table that contains column of regexp in string form.  You can then dynamically create the array of regexp objects that you'd be using to search the incoming string with.  The trick is what to do when you have a match.  You'll need to develop a set of rules (yet another table) that basically says which response to pick based on incoming text.  For example, if your rule is simply "match based on the team name and say where they play", that's pretty easy.  Each regexp that you are searching for maps to exactly one action ("The Bears play in Chicago").  If your rules are more complicated (look for the Bears, and then look to see if the word "schedule" is in there too as well as "first game(s)", then you'd need another table that maps a collection of matches to a response.